# Getting Top 3 rows where cell value is greater than

Tags: microsoft-excel

Struggling with obtaining a row of data based on the value within the row. I have my data structured like this:

```
ID  Name   Score  Owner
1   Item1  94%    MD
2   Item2  24%    OM
3   Item3  55%    TM
4   Item4  76%    MD
5   Item5  12%    OM
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to pull out the Name, and Owner where the Score is over 65% (or any other number).

I currently use column references, with my table being called "table2", eg. Table2[Name], and so forth.

Tried using INDEX and MATCH but just doesn't seem to want to work for me, also tried VLOOKUP, but again just doesn't seem to work.

Some of the formulas I have been trying and adjusting to try and achieve what I want:

```
=INDEX(Table2,MATCH(0.32,Table2[Score],-1),0)

=IF(K5="","",INDEX(Table2[Name],Table2[Score]=L5))
$K = 1 to 3 (5=1 in the above), L5 = the score I am looking for.
```

Any guidance would be really helpful, the challenge I have mostly found with examples from the internet is that they use ranges "$A$1:$A$19" etc. and when I substitute these for the named range the formula doesn't work.

Comment: Ok... So as I wrote out my answer I went back to one of the above examples to try and crack it. Seems looking at this with fresh eyes made all the difference.

Comment: How about posting your solution as an answer.  That will help others with a similar problem.

Comment: Was in the process of writing it up :) Answer now posted.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write this Array Formula in Cell `A10`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, fill it **Right** then **Down**.

  ```
    {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$D$6, SMALL(IF((INDEX($B$2:$D$6, , $B$8)>$A$8), MATCH(ROW($B$2:$D$6), ROW($B$2:$D$6)), ""), ROWS(B2:$B$2)), COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
  ```

**Note:**

- **This will extract only 2 records since has Score greater than 65%.**
- *Cell `A8` has Criteria 65% and `B8` has Column position `2` (Score column).*
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

**Edited:**

`INDEX($B$2:$D$6, , $B$8)`, becomes

`INDEX($B$2:$D$6, , 2)`

and returns `C2:C6`.

`C2:C6` is compared to $A$8 (which is 65% in this example).

`MATCH(ROW($B$2:$D$6), ROW($B$2:$D$6)), "")`

becomes,, `{1;2;3;4;5}, "")`

In combination with the IF test on `C2:C6` for `>$A$8`, returns Rows,

`{1;"";"";"";4;""}` from `Name Column`.

Finally drag the Formula Right then Down completes Data extraction.

Comment: @fixer1234, now I've edited the post & describe the mechanism  behind the search.

Comment: @fixer1234, {1;2;3;4;5}, "" are the row numbers, formula returns from Name Column and it Match in Score Column C2:C6 for > A8 (65%), returns as match Row {1;"";"",4,""} mean returns values from Row 1 & 4 only since only both has Score >65% .

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have answered my own question, after I wrote out my question I looked back at a formula I had got from https://people.highline.edu/mgirvin/excelisfun.htm particularly EMT967.xlsx which is explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKDI-kdBsjY and another from http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/28/extract-all-rows-from-a-range-that-meet-criteria-in-one-column-in-excel/. Using these 2 examples I managed to create the required formula using a combination of INDEX and MATCH.

For clarity here is what I currently have in certain cells:

W4

```
=LARGE(Table2[Score],3)
```

W5

```
3
```

K5 (Copied down 3 cells to K8)

```
=IF(ROWS(K$5:K5)>$W$5,"",ROWS(K$5:K5))
```

L5 (Copied down 3 cells to L8)

```
=IF(K5="","",LARGE(Table2[Score],K5))
```

M5 (Copied down 3 cells to M8)

```
=IF(K5="","",INDEX(Table2[Name],MATCH(L5,Table2[Score],0)))
```

If I change cell W5 to something else, such as 1 the sheet shows only the highest scoring item from my data set, 2 will show 2, and so on. If you want more than 3 copy K5, L5 and M5 down more cells, and then change the number in W5 to fill the amount of rows the formulas are in.

I hope this helps someone else, I embarrassingly spent about 6 hours trying to learn this and get it to work! But, I got it to work so that's something.

**Update**: This "works" but can't handle unique values as it only returns the first name that matches the given score.

**Update2**: Fixed using one of the examples provided previously. The Cell M5 now contains:

```
=IF(K5="","",INDEX(Table2[Name],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table2[Score])

-CELL("row",Table2[Score])+1)/(Table2[Score]=L5),COUNTIF($L$5:L5,L5))))
```

This now appears to be able to handle duplicate values.

Comment: You don't show owner.  Can we assume it's equivalent to name?  Can you add a description of how the update2 formula works, and how it handles duplicate scores?  Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could tell you exactly how it works, but I don't to be honest. Not very good I know, my only suggestion is to watch the youtube video posted above as the explains the use of the AGGREGATE function.